# javascript wrong result in division from input number fields

Tags: javascript

i have two input fields.
I have to divide one fields for the other

This is my javascript code

```
$("#circonferenza_vita").on("change",function(){
    var vita = $('#circonferenza_vita').val();
    var fianchi = $('#circonferenza_fianchi').val();
    alert(vita + " " + fianchi);
    var whr = (vita / fianchi);
    $('#whr').val(whr);
});
```

});

But when i insert the value in the input fields i have a wrong result.
For example if i insert vita 90 and fianchi 75 the result should be 0.8333 but i receive the result 1.2
Note that the alert return the correct values for vita and fianchi but the result is wrong.
Someone can help to understand and fix this issue? It is driving me crazy :)

Comment: So just divide the other way. `fianchi / vita`

Comment: I don't understand you're doing `(vita / fianchi)` so with your example, 1.2 is correct. If you want 0.83333 you should do `(fianchi / vita)`

Comment: Oh my God, sorry for the stupid question, it was my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, just swap your numbers, 90/75 = 1.2, that's right. Have a good sleep then!

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is :

```
 var whr = (vita / fianchi);
```

You said `if i insert vita 90 and fianchi 75 the result should be 0.8333 but i receive the result 1.2`. But it Should be `1.2` (`90/75`). Please Check your variables & Given Values.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I inverted the variables in division.
Thanks to all.